# Set the value of an integer passed by reference

Tags: vb.net, pass-by-reference

I am wondering how to set the value of a variable I pass by reference.  In this example, I am passing an integer, but in application, it could be a different object.

Anyways, here is a short summary of what's happening:

1. Program begins at Sub Main(), and a new form instance raised.  The form's constructor is a ByRef argument.
2. Upon executing the New() sub, this argument is saved in a private member of the form instance.
3. The user presses a button, and said private member is assigned a value.
4. Why isn't the original result changed too?  (It's still 0 instead of 5555)

Code example:

```
Option Strict On

Public Class SpecialForm
    Inherits System.Windows.Forms.Form
    Private WithEvents _Btn As System.Windows.Forms.Button = Nothing
    Private _Result As Integer
    Public Sub New(ByRef Out_Result As Integer)
        _Result = Out_Result
    End Sub
    Private Sub SpecialForm_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        _Btn = New System.Windows.Forms.Button
        With _Btn
            'Set size
            'Set location
            'Set text
            'etc
        End With
        Me.Controls.Add(_Btn)
    End Sub
    Private Sub Btn_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles _Btn.Click
        _Result = 5555
        Me.Close()
    End Sub
End Class

Module EntryPoint
    Public Sub Main()
        Dim result As Integer
        Using mySpecialForm As New SpecialForm(result)
            mySpecialForm.ShowDialog()
        End Using
        MsgBox(String.Format("The result is {0}", result)) 'DEBUG MESSAGE
    End Sub
End Module
```

Maybe I'm doing it wrong, or maybe it's a limitation of the language.  But is there any way to do this without using a global?

Comment: Integers are value types - when you assign one to another, the values are copied, but there is no linkage between the two.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The statement `_Result = Out_Result` stores the value of Out_Result not its address.
You should use an instance of a class such as:

```
Class MyData
    public value as integer
End Class
```

You can the do something like:

```
_Result.value = 5555
```